# vmagent lose only one metric's data point，what is the possible reason?

Tags: victoriametrics

I am use VictoriaMetrics operator to collect metrics in kubernetes cluster, and I found vmagent lose only one metric's data point, all other metrics looks fine, what's the possible reason?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is likely caused by irregular scrapes of the target, which affects staleness detection. In two words, if target was scraped for some time each 15s and then 3-4 or more scrapes failed - you'll have a gap on the graph.
To reduce this effect, try setting `-search.minStalenessInterval` cmd-line flag for vmselect to value between 1 or 5min. For example, Prometheus has it set to 5min.
To get more details about what happens there check https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/3878

Answer (score 1):

Add the `-promscrape.noStaleMarkers` option of vmagent solve the problem.